# Black Text-Background on cell-based NSTableView with Sourcelist Highlight style (10.12)

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, appkit

I have noticed an issue under macOS 10.12: When I create a NSTableView with "Sourcelist" Highlight style, the Text-Cells draw a black background while being edited, making the text black on black and actually unreadable.

I wonder if anybody else ran into this issue and if there is a possible workaround.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround by subclassing `NSTextFieldCell` and make it return a subclass of `NSTextTextView` as its field editor. 
This subclass needs to override `- drawsBackground` returning NO.
Setting this property after initialization does not seem to be enough.

```c
@interface NonBackgroundDrawingTextView : NSTextView

@end


@implementation NonBackgroundDrawingTextView

- (BOOL)drawsBackground {
    return NO;
}

@end

@interface CustomTextFieldCell : NSTextFieldCell

@end

@implementation CustomTextFieldCell

- (NSTextView *)fieldEditorForView:(NSView *)controlView {
    static NSMutableDictionary* FieldEditors = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        FieldEditors = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    });
    if (FieldEditors[@(controlView.hash)]) {
        return FieldEditors[@(controlView.hash)];
    }
    NSTextView* textView = [[NonBackgroundDrawingTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    [textView setFieldEditor:YES];
    [textView setFocusRingType:NSFocusRingTypeExterior];
    FieldEditors[@(controlView.hash)] = textView;
    return textView;
}

@end
```